# Google adsense auto ads overlay my site contect

Tags: php, html, adsense

when i enable auto ads in my site I found that it is overlapping overy object in body like navigation bar, search bar, etc. If anyone have idea how to solve plz reply below:

My website is HTML website not php or anything else.

Comment: Are you talking about anchor ads (top sticky ad) or a banner ad? Also please provide url to your website if it's available publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for a couple of days and Google's AI will automatically render the ads efficiently.
Also, you should embed some custom ad codes manually. This will show fewer auto ads to your site.

Comment: ads also overlay when i use costom ads

Comment: I think you may have a problem with your template CSS. Provide the website's URL if you can. @SmilePant